# An internal error occured in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller name `ReminderController` from which I wanna call `admin_index.ctp`.

```
class ReminderController  extends AppController {
    public function admin_index(){
        $this->paginate=array('limit' =>'10');

        $this->set('news', $this->paginate('Reminder'));    

    }
```

When I call view name admin_index from a controller I found an internal error has been occurred... please help me out from this problem.........

Comment: Check tmp/logs/error.log and set your debug level in the config to 2 while you are developing.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cakephp, but according to me error is in below 2 lines:

```
$this->paginate=array('limit' =>'10');

$this->set('news', $this->paginate('Reminder'));
```

Because, in the first line you are assigning an array to $this->paginate. But in the second line you are calling it as a function.